# How to write logs of external library in android ?

Tags: android, android-library

I use external library (ru.truba.touchgallery) in my application. It shows images by viewpager.Its properties , touch zoom in , zoom out, sliding images etc.  My application throws en error in the activity which uses this library. The error output is below.So, How can write logs of touchgallery library to android studio's console by Log class ?

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
                        at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
                        at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2010)
                        at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
                        at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:110)
                        at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:462)
                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1916)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2059)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2383)
                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1724)
                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2764)
                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
                        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
                        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
                        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: where does this log you posted come from?

Comment: It comes from console. But it is general error.  I wanna debugging and logging to solve my problem.

Comment: if you want to debug a 3rd party lib, you'll need it's source code

Comment: I  already have this source code.

Comment: so remove the lib's dependency, and add the source code to your project, then recompile and start debugging it